# Uncaught ReferenceError: require not defined (electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to create a quote widget on electron. For renderer process, I created index.js and coded like below

```
console.log('from renderer');

var request = require('request');
const electron = require('electron');


var url ="https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?orderby=rand&_="+rnd;

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if(error)
    {
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = 'Unable to fetch the quote plaese check the network connection';
        return;
    }
    let bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bodyJson);
    let randomQuote = bodyJSON[0]["content"]["rendered"];
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = randomQuote;
});
```

And index.html has

```
<div id="quote">

</div>
<script src="index.js">
    // require ('index.js');
</script>
```

If I use `require ('index.js');` in `script` tag, it doesn't work. So I used `src="index.js"`. Now renderer process works but on console, it shows `"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:3"`
My 1st query is why `require ('index.js');` on `script` tag doesn't work on `index.html`
and 2nd query is how to fix the `Uncaught ReferenceError` problem on `index.js`
My electron version is v8.2.0 and node version is v12.16.1 and dependencies on `package.json` are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "require": "^2.4.20"
    }
```

Anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Electron 5, Node integration in the renderer process is disabled by default. To get around that, you need to declare `nodeIntegration: true` when instantiating your `BrowserWindow`.

```js
// In the main process.
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

Edit: As of Electron 12, you'll also need to define `contextIsolation: false` in order to do this, as the default value of the flag has changed.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-contextisolation-defaults-to-true

Comment: This worked for me, I did not need to change the 'context' variable either, but I cannot get it to work if I try the electron app as a webpage to utilize 'liveserver' in parallel since it seems that having this exposes the user to security risk. So the app as a webpage cannot use 'require'

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `require ('index.js');` doesn't work in the script tag is because `require` isn't defined for the browser. It is only defined for Node. The reason why you are getting the `ReferenceError` in index.js is because what `<script src="index.js>` is actually doing is running the code in index.js in the browser environment. So since it is being run in the browser `require` isn't defined here also.

Comment: Yes, I understood that and thank you for your reply.